# Memory issue with UIGETDIR

Tags: matlab, memory-management

Recently, I have noticed an odd behavior from `uigetdir` function of MATLAB.

If I have a string with some values, it has almost no effect on the memory.

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:    860 MB (9.014e+08 bytes)
Memory available for all arrays:   1287 MB (1.349e+09 bytes)
Memory used by MATLAB:    435 MB (4.557e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3317 MB (3.478e+09 bytes)

>> folder = 'C:\Users\MrAwesome';

>> memory
Maximum possible array:    860 MB (9.014e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1289 MB (1.352e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    434 MB (4.553e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3317 MB (3.478e+09 bytes)
```

But if I use `uigetdir` instead, it drains down a whole lot of memory:

```
>> folder2 = uigetdir;

>> memory
Maximum possible array:    727 MB (7.628e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1153 MB (1.208e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    458 MB (4.806e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3317 MB (3.478e+09 bytes)
```

And if I clear these two variables from my memory, it will not release the memory!

I looked it up, and found nothing on this issue anywhere.

**First**, I would like to know how to use (or **what to use instead of**) `uigetdir` effectively?
**Second**, I would like to know how to **free the memory** from some functions/variables like this?

Comment: Can you tell us what version of MATLAB you're using, and also verify that you're using the built-in uigetdir?
which -all uigetdir

Comment: R2013a, and yes it is the built-in function.

Comment: i just tried this myself and the only similar drop is if i don't use `clc` and `clear all` between the tests

Comment: The different between assigning a string and `uigetdir` is obviously, since with `uigetdir`, Matlab must use many more functions than the first option. You can use `inmem` to see which functions are being used / stored in memory. But for the `clear`, i am also have the same problem like yours, tried with r2013b and r2014a, next week after holidays i can try on r2014b on the institute ...

Comment: update: something even more strange: after posted the last comment, i came back to matlab with `uigetdir` once again, and whoops, memory reduced ^_^ `memory` --> `Memory used by MATLAB: 708 MB` --> `f2 = uigetdir;` --> `memory` --> `Memory used by MATLAB: 700 MB` ... just about 5min later, Matlab is self-optimizing?